# Find the area of rectangle?

Tags: problem-solving

Can any body tell me what is the algorithm I have to follow to solve this problem?

**A rectangle has length:breadth in $5:4$. A square's side is $50\%$ greater than breadth of the rectangle. The area of the square is $384$. Find the area of the rectangle?**

Comment: Hi, @Akshay Kumar, Welcome to MSE. Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and see some questions/answers to get a better idea of how to ask a good question. These things will help you in understanding the working of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the sides of rectangle are $5x$(length) and $4x$(breadth). Now, the side of square will be $6x$ ($50$% more than breadth of rectangle).

Now it is given to you that $(6x)^2=384$ which will give you $x=\sqrt \frac{32} {3}$.i Now area of rectangle is $5x\times 4x=20\times 32/3=640/3$.